# Can I run a single SELECT rather than two nested to link two tables, omitting dupes, and return value if they match? MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

total n00b here, first post, so please be constructive! I've bought a book to teach myself PHP / MySQL - and not one which is universally praised, unfortunately - so my progress is a bit erratic.

I have two tables which I want to link. I want to display all of the information held in table 1 (let's call it Records), but ONLY once. I then want to check whether each item in Records has a match to a specific field in table 2 (UserTable) and if it does, display a ticked checkbox, or an empty checkbox if there's no match.

The issues I've had to date are only displaying the items from Records where there's a match, or displaying multiple instances of each item in Records where there are multiple matches. I've solved these with the code below - but I keep thinking there must be a better way to do this, perhaps with a single link?

Anyway, here are some excerpts from the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Records";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

while ($iteminfo = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$recordid2 = $iteminfo['record_id'];
```

I've omitted a section which pulls out the relevant data from Records and starts to build a table, then:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS matches FROM UserTable 
where usertable.item = '$recordid2' and User_ID = '$current_user_id'";

$res2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql2);
$matches = mysqli_fetch_array($res2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$matches2 = $matches['matches'];

if ($matches2) {
        $output = "<input type='checkbox' name='test' checked>"; } else {
        $output = "<input type='checkbox' name='test'>";
```

As I say, this works, but it feels a bit clumsy - I'm running a separate nested query for every item in Records, which over time could become really slow. Is there a way to run a single query for the whole which brings through all of the row info (once) and a 0 or 1 depending on whether there is a match in UserTable? I've tried using DISTINCT but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT * FROM Records
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT usertable.item, COUNT(User_ID) AS matches FROM UserTable
    WHERE User_ID = '$current_user_id'
    GROUP BY usertable.item
) as UserTable ON record_id = usertable.item
```

This fetches ALL records, and also only the matching rows for the given User ID in UserTable (change the User ID to fetch details for a different user).

If a row in Record exists, but no matching row exists in UserTable, then "matches" will be NULL. Otherwise it should be a numeric value greater than zero.

Just run this in PHP to handle the checkbox stuff. (it checks for matches greater than zero, and only if found, will print out the "checked" attribute)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" <?=((int)$record['matches'] > 0) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
```

Comment: Hi Wireblue, thanks for the post - it looks like an elegant solution, just what I need! Just my PHP skills letting me down now... I've been building everything by concatenating $output and then using ECHO, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "Just run this in PHP"...? Cheers!

Comment: Ok. You can either use the output code in your original post and replace `if ($matches2) {` with `if ((int)$record['matches'] > 0) {` or probably a better solution (which will require a bit of work) is to separate your PHP logic from your HTML.

I usually put my PHP logic at the top of the file, and then my HTML at the bottom, and sprinkle in <?=$my_var?> tags in amongst the HTML tags for the output. Sometimes you will simply have to put in PHP Logic into the HTML part, and that's ok, but wherever possible try and leave the "heavy-lifting" logic at the top.

Comment: Cracked it - I was using $iteminfo where you were using $record, all working now! Many thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Well done for noticing that the approach is clumsy.  Take some time to look at the SQL language and better understand it.  In particular you want to learn how to JOIN.  Probably an INNER JOIN.  Other types are FULL OUTER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

I suggest that rather than doing the joining in the procedural code you do it in the SQL.  Then make a single call to the DB, e.g.

```
select records.field1, records.field2, matches.field1, matches.field2
from records
   , matches
where records.field = matches.field;
```

Play with this query until you get the results you want then call this from PHP

```
$sql = <query from above>
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
```

One good thing about this is that the SQL language is fairly transferable.  Everything form Access to Oracle uses a similar syntax.  And you can use this knowledge regardless of the procedural language you're working with (PHP, .NET, etc)

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Karl, thanks for the encouragement - I'll definitely look at the JOIN types as you suggest. Cheers!